# Retrieving geo location in react-native without GPS

Tags: react-native

I'm searching for a solution to fetch geolocation on android and iOS through react-native without using the GPS.

It doesn't seem like the default [geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) module supports this, or am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the function `getCurrentLocation` takes an object of options as the last parameter which enables the location to be based on cell tower triangulation (or otherwise - at least without hitting the GPS).

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
    this.setState({initialPosition});
  },
  (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
  {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
);
```

Notice the **enableHighAccuracy: false** property.